# Using TextTools in Ada

Tags: gcc, ada

I wanna use [TextTools](http://home.online.no/~runeberg/tt/tthome.htm) in a Ada program. Does anybody have a tutorial giving instructions how to start? 
I'm getting an error when trying to compile my  C_code/curses.c (I'm using texttools-2.0.7).

Comment: I presume you're following the instructions in the doc/usermanual.html file. What have you done, what error(s) are you seeing? On what platform (Linux, Windows, FreeBSD) are you running?

Comment: Generally saying "I'm getting an error" isn't enough information here on SO (or much of anywhere else). You should post the exact error message.

Comment: I presume you're using Gnu Ada (GNAT) along with gcc.  They should coexist fine.  Q: what exactly is the compile error you're getting?